# How to add large file content into websocket request in Postman

Tags: websocket, postman

I'm using Postman to test an WebSocket server.
The server will send and receive files via WebSocket.

Is this possible to add large file content (~3GB) into WebSocket request in Postman?

I searched all learning center of Postman, and I found that Postman supported to [Importing data files](https://learning.postman.com/docs/collections/running-collections/working-with-data-files/) with HTTP requests.
But I could not find a guideline to send file content with WebSocket.